# Missing CSRF cookie in response when trying to deal with redirect/login

Tags: node.js, csrf, supertest, http-status-code-302

I am simply trying to replicate a python based login script for an app (django/react) using node & supertest (or supertest-session). I am a bit stumped and assume I am missing something very basic but what I am seeing is: if I call the app url with Curl, or using python/requests in a shell, or using postman I get back 2 cookies - 1 for the sessionId, 1 for the csrf token. When using supertest or supertest-session I only seem to get the sessionId cookie back in the set-cookie header. I can't seem to find any reference in the response to the csrf token. Hoping someone with better insight can point me in the right direction or let me know what I'm overlooking or missing in my request in this case that would rectify the situation.

Answer (score 0):

.redirect(1) was missing from the request. That was the obvious thing I overlooked.